# Installing biber on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, biber

My tex file has `backend=biber` in the header. But, as I use tex-live 2009, biber is not installed by default. I downloaded the biber.tar.gz from the biber project page at sourceforg., When I extracted it, it had only one file named `biber`. I placed it in `/usr/bin` dir and made it executable. And I ran `biber my_paper.aux` and it showed an error: `/usr/bin not found`.

I cloned the git dev project of biber. And when I tried building it, it showed up lots of dependancy issues.

So is there an easy way to get biber working on my 32bit ubuntu 11.04 system?

Comment: Is installing TeXlive 2011 an option? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I've installed `biber` on both 32- and 64-bit versions of Ubuntu in essentially the same way you described with no problems, although I put the extracted `biber` in `/usr/local/bin`.  The error you describe sounds strange, though.  What happens if you run (say):

```
/usr/bin/cal
```

..?

If that works as expected, then I'd delete older versions of `biber`, extract a new copy, make it executable, and try this sequence:

- first: make sure `backend=biber` is an option you're giving to `biblatex`;
- run your file (my_paper.tex) through (say) `latex` (this should create a file with a `.bcf` extension);
- then run `biber my_paper` or `biber my_paper.bcf` (*not* `biber my_paper.aux`).

If you're having trouble with these steps, then can you even run `biber -v` to check your version.  (I get `biber version: 0.9.6 (beta)` when I run the command.)

Another thing to check is that your `biblatex` and its related packages (`etoolbox`, `logreq`, and, ideally, `csquotes`) are also up to date --- although I can't see how this could relate to the more profound error you seem to be experiencing.

EDIT: you may want to look at the `biber` documentation as well:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/documentation/